# How to export animations and morph keys to glTF?

Tags: animation, shape-keys, three.js

I have a .blend project obtained from DAZ to Blender bridge.

On my timeline there are both bone animations and morph shape keys that I want to export to glTF for Three.js.

Currently exporting with the following options only exports bone animations without any morphs (tried importing back in blender).

[image: Export Settings]

I have also tried to push down actions as NLA Strips. What should I do to get both bone animations and morphs to work when I export to Blender or Three.js?

Comment: This should "just work" unless something is unusual about the file, your settings are right. Are you able to post a `.blend` that has this problem?

Comment: @DonMcCurdy I've uploaded the .blend file here: https://we.tl/t-7nRKdAcj5L
The project has both animations and morphs but on export the facial morphs somehow move to the fingers and toes.

Comment: three.js has a limit of 4-8 morph keys active per mesh at a time, and this model appears to have many, which may be why it's not animating as expected. Viewing in https://sandbox.babylonjs.com/, which doesn't have that restriction, it looks OK to me. Disabling "Shape Key Normals" will increase the limit from 4 to 8 in three.js, which may help some.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy Thanks so much for your help. What I ended up doing is accessing each of the individual morphs using `mesh.morphTargetInfluences`, then adjusting and animating the morphs using Tweens.